# Which process Visual Studio has to attach to run DNX process?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dnx

I ran a Web API that I created with the command **dnx web**. The service is running fine and I get the result too.

I want to attach the Visual Studio Process to this dnx process and debug the API call. Which process I need to attach to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dnx-watch. this show the dnx process.
It also automatic restart the server after code change

A fast way to debug is to insert `Debugger.Launch();` in your code, on the place where you want to start to debug.

It is faster than attach to the right process

dnx-watch can be installed by

```
dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher
```